# How to know whether 2 characters will rank exactly the same way under utf8 collation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, utf-8, collation

I took the unusual approach of using actual words and title as primary keys. Of course those must be unique.

Many characters that are different in vb.net count as the same in mysql

Just look at [Normalize All UTF8 Character into it's most standard format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354999/normalize-all-utf8-character-into-its-most-standard-format#comment14955996_11354999)

I want a way for vb.net to know that they're the same thing.

Comment: KeyTable, Identity, Seq's, Guid/Combs are all standard primary key methods, why use words? To make VB.Net recognize them the same as mysql do you have a list of which ones's mysql considers the same?

Comment: you can see lists at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354999/normalize-all-utf8-character-into-its-most-standard-format#comment14955996_11354999